Reactivate Record Variable Passed to LWC from Screen Flow
So, I have managed to get the reactivity to work as expected when its just a string variable.
HTML File

    <lightning-button  label="Click" title="SaveButton" onclick={onClick} ></lightning-button>

</template>

JS File
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';


export default class CustomPSOFooter extends LightningElement {

    @api proj; 
    @api newProj; 
   
    @api projRec; 
    onClick() {
       
        console.log( this.proj); 
       

    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.projRec))); 
    }


    
}

Meta File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <masterLabel>Custom Footer Comopnent</masterLabel>
    <description>This is a simple todos component</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>

        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="proj" type="String" label=" Project Record Varialbe" description=""/>
            <property name="projRec" type="@salesforce/schema/Project__c" label="Project Record Variable" description=""/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

But, when I try to work with passing a Record Variable it fails to recognize that the screen flow input has changed.
Modified JS File
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';


export default class CustomPSOFooter extends LightningElement {

    @api proj; 
    @api newProj; 

    @api projRec; 
    onClick() {

        console.log( this.projRec); 


    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.projRec))); 
    }



}

Screenshot of if I add a text variable to the LWC to show the changes in the Text Field (which is a screen flow input)

Screenshot of if I try to use a field that updates a record variable (aka Requestor Name) , with the record variable initiated via an assignment element


How is anyone going to replicate your issue with the information you've provided? Please take the time to edit your question to include reproducable steps so people can help you.  As it stands, you have an HTML file that is incomplete, screenshots that doesn't even show your LWC, and a 'modified' js file that's almost exacctly the same, with no indication of what's different or why it's different.

Agree with Nick's comment above. I'm not sure if it's just because you have provided incomplete code snippets, but from what you have provided you're not firing the FlowAttributeChange event when the variable is updated, so the Flow has no way of knowing that the component has updated. You'd need something like const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('attributename', event.target.value);
